# Where to find hiking shorts that last more than a few months?

Tags: hiking, clothing

I'm one of these crazy people that tend to wear cargo shorts all year round, and do a lot of hiking and general outdoor activities in them. However, because of this they tend to wear out relatively quickly, and I haven't yet found some that last beyond a few months.

Has anyone any recommendations? I'm quite big (40" waist) which doesn't help! I'd also like ones with lots of pockets which narrows it down further.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it primarily a shopping question.  It is an old question, that I believe does not meet the current expectations of this site.

Comment: @JamesJenkins I appreciate your explanation. When this came forward yesterday, I wanted to do the same thing, but wasn't sure if I should. No offense meant at all berry120, but I'm adding my close vote to the group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been using the same two pair of swimshorts for years now.  They dry quick, they're lightweight, they're cheap.  Mine are [similar to these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0048BP0UM) (with pockets, but not lots), but I got mine at Target.

The only downside is that sometimes the cheap thin string tie bites into my waist on really long summer hikes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I've found a couple of problems though, like you mentioned I find the string is generally thin and bites quite a bit. The second is the lack of pockets (I've updated the question with this now.)

Comment: Mine have pockets ;)

Comment: And yours have withstood blackberry brambles most admirably.

Answer (score 2):

When I hiked the PCT, I wore NosiLife Cargo Shorts, from Craghopper.

I wore them continuously for 4 months before I began to wear them out.  They would have lasted longer, but I lost so much weight they would no longer stay up.

They did get a bit thin in the bum, but that was due to me glissading and  falling on my arse a lot.